# Can I access the selected data in a Chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

I have created a User Interface with Google Apps Script that shows data in Charts object like TableChart and PieChart.

Charts objects allow the user to select a section of the pie and multiple lines in the table. I would like my code to know what are the selected data in the charts.

I there a way to do that ?
If not I will fill a feature request in the GAS issue tracker.

Thanks

Thierry

Comment: Having no solution I filled a feature request, if you are interested in such a feature, please click on the star in the [request page](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2351)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I close this question as it is now clear that there is currently no solution to access the selected data in a Chart using GAS.

A feature request has been filled here http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2351.

The feature request has been accepted. I will edit this answer once the new feature is implemented.

Cheers,

Thierry

Answer (score 2):

Yes. See the documentation for [getSelection()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#visgetselection)

> **getSelection() [optional]**
>
> This is optionally exposed by visualizations that want to let you
>   access the currently selected data in the graphic.
>
> ```
> selection_array getSelection()
> ```
>
> **Returns**
>
> selection_array   An array of selected objects, each one describing a
>   data element in the underlying table used to create the visualization
>   (a DataView or a DataTable). Each object has properties row and/or
>   column, with the index of the row and/or column of the selected item
>   in the underlying DataTable. If the row property is null, then the
>   selection is a column; if the column property is null, then the
>   selection is a row; if both are non-null, then it is a specific data
>   item. You can call the DataTable.getValue() method to get the value of
>   the selected item. The retrieved array can be passed into
>   setSelection().
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> function myClickHandler(){
>   var selection = myVis.getSelection();
>
>
>   for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++) {
>     var item = selection[i];
>     if (item.row != null && item.column != null) {
>       message += '{row:' + item.row + ',column:' + item.column + '}';
>     } else if (item.row != null) {
>       message += '{row:' + item.row + '}';
>     } else if (item.column != null) {
>       message += '{column:' + item.column + '}';
>     }
>   }
>   if (message == '') {
>     message = 'nothing';
>   }
>   alert('You selected ' + message);
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you but the solution you provide is for javascript in browser and not for Google Apps Script which executes serverside.

I do not find an equivalent in GAS. The first main problem is that I do not know how to access the Chart object in a callback function triggered by a handler.

Then I will need an equivalent to the getSelection function which I think does not exist.